# DialogFragment custom style does not work

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog, android-dialogfragment

I have an `AlertDialog` which is styled to match my app's theme. I decided to move that dialog to a `DialogFragment`, and the custom style is no longer working.

Here is the relevant code in the `DialogFragment`:

```java
@NonNull
@Override
public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return new AlertDialog.Builder(requireContext(), R.style.CustomAlertDialogTheme)
            .setView(R.layout.my_dialog)
            .setCancelable(false)
            .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.cancel,
                    (dialog, which) -> dismiss())
            .setMessage(R.string.my_message)
            .create();
}
```

And here is the relevant code in the `styles.xml`:

```xml
<style name="CustomAlertDialogTheme" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dialog.Alert">
    <item name="buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/NegativeButtonStyle</item>
    <item name="buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/PositiveButtonStyle</item>
</style>

<style name="NegativeButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/textbutton_text_color_selector</item>
</style>

<style name="PositiveButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.ButtonBar.AlertDialog">
    <item name="android:textColor">@drawable/textbutton_text_color_selector</item>
</style>
```

I've also tried using `setStyle` in various places in the `DialogFragment` without success. I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct `AlertDialog` class imported? Looks like you're set up for `androidx.appcompat.app.AlertDialog`, rather than `android.app.AlertDialog`.

Comment: That was it.. Thanks so much for your help. 1 hour wasted for that!